# How to map one-to-one set $A$ into set $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the ordered set $$A=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}.$$
I need to map the elements of set $A$ into elements of set $$B=\{0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3\}.$$
I have tried to use the function: $B_i=(A_i+4) \mod 4,  i=1,2,...,10$.

My result is: $$B'=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1\}.$$

**Question.** How to rewrite the function in order to map set $A$ to set $B$?

Comment: Is $B$ a multiset, or does $B$ contain only four elements? Or are you trying to find a function that maps $0\mapsto0,1\mapsto3,2\mapsto2,3\mapsto1,4\mapsto0$ etc...?

Comment: Hint: $4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3$.

Comment: I am trying to find a function that maps 0↦0,1↦3,2↦2,3↦1,4↦0 etc.

Comment: If the previous hint did not get to you, think of $0, -1, -2, -3, -4, \cdots$ How can you turn this array of integers into $B$?

Comment: $-A_i \mod 4$ works.

Comment: Glad that it worked!

Comment: As the set B has 4 elements and  A has 10, there cannot be a bijection between them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** How can you turn $0,−1,−2,−3,−4,\cdots$ into B?

The observation comes from the idea that $3, 2, 1$ is a recurring descending subsequence. Since the mod operator is allowed, we can let $0$ into this party by modding everything $0,-1,-2,-3,-4,\cdots$ by $4$.